# How can I get a package of gazebo7 with a specific issue fixed?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I need to work with the LogicalCameraSensor and apparently there was a bug when recognizing nested models:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/commits/68d94d3cce38

Seems that Ubuntu's packages do not have this commit included, so I tried with the nightly and prerelease tutorial:
http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_unstable&cat=install

I manage to get gazebo7.8.1 or gazebo8.1.1 and both show that same behavior, seems to me that the release dates are prior to the issue merge date.

I need to use ROS Kinetic and I think that it do not supports gazebo9, right? There will be no more gazebo7/8 nightly's to be published? is there a way to "push" someone to release this packages? (tried to compile from source and failed)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17877/how-can-i-get-a-package-of-gazebo7-with-a-specific-issue-fixed?/) by [lecato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4150/lecato/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You're right that the fix hasn't been released yet, see [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d7411f63727d3e09eeed4a1175a01801eb69314c/Changelog.md?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Unlike major releases, which happen on schedule once per year, minor/patch releases may happen anytime, depending on the number of changes and the urgency for the fixes. Unfortunately we don't have an official way for users to express their need for a release (that would be nice though) besides either posting a question here or creating an issue. I'll bring it up internally.

I don't recommend Gazebo 9 / default right now if you're looking for something stable. That will be released on January 2018.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lecato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4150/lecato/) on 2017-11-21**:
Great, thanks! last release is from a few months ago, looks like a good time for an update!

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-11-29**:
@lecato, forgot to let you know, Gazebo 7.9 was released last week.

**Comment by [lecato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4150/lecato/) on 2017-11-29**:
yes I noticed, thank you very much! I already unhacked my world files using the  tag properly and the logical camera sensor is working great. Feels so good when open source community works!